# Random element in a set

Tags: c++

I have a set like this:

```
set<vector<prmNode> > cammini
```

I need to take 2 random values (2 random vector) from this set. How could I do??
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to do the following twice.

```
*(std::advance(cammini.begin(), rand() % cammini.size()))
```

You can do it more efficiently if you generate two indexes, advance by the smaller and then advance by the difference between them.

Comment: Note that this is biased towards smaller indexes.

Comment: @Johannes, I don't think so. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Assuming `rand() % constant` is biased which it tends to be. The idea itself works, given non-biased random number generation, but a set is probably not a container of choice for picking random values out of.

Comment: Ah, of course, `rand() % k` is biased (regardless of the quality of `rand` itself), but it's the best one can do without involving Boost.Random or writing a non-trivial piece of code.

Comment: Unless `RAND_MAX` is an exact multiple of `cammini.size()` you will get the smaller indexes a little more often than the larger ones since you're using a modulus here. That's always the problem when using `%` to get a pseudo-random number up to *n*. It is less of a problem if `RAND_MAX` is larger but for some implementations it's ridiculously small. Basically you get (size/n) equal-sized intervals of *n* elements each and at the end of the `rand()` range one interval which is smaller. Every number falling into that last, smaller interval skews the distribution in your [0, *n*) interval.

Comment: Well, for a fairly concise and elegant piece of code how to deal with it, you could take a look at java.util.Random.nextInt(int). But yes, omitting such an elemental piece of functionality from C and even C++ is a bit frustrating at times.